# Windows 10 не записывается con.png file

Tags: windows

Пытаюсь разархивировать zip, не получается, и все время из-за `con.png` файла. Подумал что архив испорченный и попробовал из гугла скачать картинку, переименовать в `con.png`, не получилось. Где-то прочитал, что в `win` существуют зарезервированные какие то слова.

Кто нибудь знает, как это обойти, кроме как удалить его из архива?

Comment: Можно распаковать при помощи 7-zip. Он при распаковке сам переименует con.png в con_,png. Еще можно распаковать посредством Far Manager, но тогда после распаковки файл придется переименовывать самостоятельно, поскольку большинство программ его все равно не сможет открыть.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно переименовать.

Да, действительно, в Windows есть [зарезервированные слова](https://www.itroad.ru/sistemnye-imena-con-nul-prn-aux-com1-com2-com3-com4-com5-com6-com7-com8-com9-lpt1-lpt2-lpt3-lpt4-lpt5-lpt6-lpt7-lpt8-lpt9), которые не могут использоваться для задания имен файлов, и `con` — одно из них.
Почему так? Это ограничение еще со времен MS DOS, когда эти ключевые слова были зарезервированы для устройств ввода-вывода. Тот же `con` - сокращение от "консоль", если верно помню.

Не претендуя на полный список зарезервированных слов, попробую их перечислить:
`con, nul, prn, AUX, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, LPT9`  при этом регистр букв значения не имеет, если опять же, не ошибаюсь.

Вы же пытаетесь создать файл с именем `con.png`, где имя - `con` и оно зарезервировано, а расширение `png` - это всё же расширение, и в данном случае может быть любым, так что создать такой файл не получится. хотя можно создать файл `con.png`*схожий* по написанию - заменив английские буквы `c` или `o` на аналогичные русские. В этом случае схожесть будет лишь внешняя, ибо имя-то будет другим. При этом делать так (смешивать алфавиты) **строго не рекомендуется**.

Решением будет открыть архив, например, в WinRAR и переименовать этот файл в, например, `_con.png`. Или сохранять с гугла картинку в файл с именем, отличным от `con`.

Comment: Ну это тоже самое что и удалить его :)

Comment: Нет, все же переименовать файл в архиве и удалить его из архива - немного разное, как мне кажется )

Comment: @BlackWitcher Был файл xyz.png преименовали в абс.png , то получается что xyz.png файл удален  потомучто нету такого файла с таким названием..

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan. Нет. Ошибочно рассуждаете. Файл переименован, а не удален. Если рассуждать как вы, то если человек к примеру, поменял фамилию, то нет такого человека больше, а это не так - человек остался, изменилась лишь фамилия :) Вот и с вашим примером так же - файл остался, но его имя изменилось.